# Extruding with precision and proportions

Tags: extrude

How can I make these kind of operations and extrusions and make it look smooth, proportional and keeping it low poly?

[image: gif of example]

Any methods to share?

Comment: You can create a bezier curve and position it as needed, Bevel Object can be used (another curve) if you're looking for customizable profile. Position the control points according to your desired result and once done convert to mesh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I'm extruding, then I hold down control and left-click. This method is keeping it proportional. Another method is by using curves - you parent mesh to curve and then you can easily edit wires and such things. I hope this post helped you.

Comment: Sorry, didn't quite understand what you mean by holding down "contor" (contour that is I believe?).

Comment: Control/ command/ ctrl. You select vertices you want to extrude. Then hold down the ctrl button and left-click. Its extruding.